# Условие локализации

Tags: java, android, локализация

Приложение поддерживает несколько языков, однако на одном из языков есть дополнительные функции, для этого требуется сделать условие, что если например язык локализации русский, то определенные `view` элементы сделать видимыми, в противном случае скрывать их. Так вот как сделать такое условие?

Comment: Создать в `layout-ru` одноимённый макет с нужной компоновкой.

Comment: @woesss можете вывести в ответы, отмечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для различных конфигураций можно создавать альтернативные ресурсы, в том числе и макеты. Для этого нужно создать ресурс с таким же именем в соответствующей папке с квалификатором нужной конфигурации.

```
res/
    layout/   
        activity_main.xml   
    layout-ru/  
        activity_main.xml
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources